# how to do subtotal and total at the same time

Tags: r

I have a df that looks like this, and I would like to get the sub total for mathand ELA as well as all. How could I do that?

[image]

Sample data can be build using codes:

```
df<-structure(list(Math1 = c(5, 6, 2, NA, 3), Math2 = c(8, NA, 2, 
4, NA), Math3 = c(2, 2, 9, 6, 6), Math4 = c(3, 8, NA, 7, 3), 
    ELA1 = c(4, 4, 6, 7, 8), ELA2 = c(5, NA, 5, 9, NA), ELA3 = c(3, 
    4, 7, NA, 7)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I tried to reach my goal using following codes, but they are not working:

```
df<- df_dose1 %>% 
            mutate(Total = rowSums(across(where(is.numeric)), na.rm=T),
                   Total.M=rowSums(across(where(grepl("Math",  colnames(df)))), na.rm=T),
                   Total.E=rowSums(across(where(!grepl("Math",  colnames(df)))), na.rm=T))
```

Where did i do wrong? anyone can guide me on this? or even better, if you you have better way to present those info.

The final output should looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rowSums` should be applied on the `select`ed columns

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Total = rowSums(., na.rm = TRUE), .before = 'Math1') %>%
  mutate(Total.M = rowSums(select(., starts_with('Math')),
           na.rm = TRUE), .before = 'Math1') %>%
  mutate(Total.E =  rowSums(select(., starts_with('ELA')),
           na.rm = TRUE), .before = 'ELA1')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 10
#  Total Total.M Math1 Math2 Math3 Math4 Total.E  ELA1  ELA2  ELA3
#  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    30      18     5     8     2     3      12     4     5     3
#2    24      16     6    NA     2     8       8     4    NA     4
#3    31      13     2     2     9    NA      18     6     5     7
#4    33      17    NA     4     6     7      16     7     9    NA
#5    27      12     3    NA     6     3      15     8    NA     7
```

---

`across` loops over the columns and it is used mainly to apply some function individually on each column separately.  But, there is `c_across` that can be applied on rows after grouping by rows (`rowwise`).  Here, the function would be `sum` (it would be less efficient to do this operation)

```
df %>%
      rowwise %>%
      mutate(Total = sum(c_across(where(is.numeric)), na.rm = TRUE),
             Total.M= sum(c_across(starts_with('Math')), na.rm = TRUE),
             Total.E = sum(c_across(starts_with('ELA')), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
     ungroup %>% 
     select(Total, Total.M, starts_with('Math'), Total.E, starts_with('ELA'))
# A tibble: 5 x 10
#  Total Total.M Math1 Math2 Math3 Math4 Total.E  ELA1  ELA2  ELA3
#  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    30      18     5     8     2     3      12     4     5     3
#2    24      16     6    NA     2     8       8     4    NA     4
#3    31      13     2     2     9    NA      18     6     5     7
#4    33      17    NA     4     6     7      16     7     9    NA
#5    27      12     3    NA     6     3      15     8    NA     7
```

Comment: Wow! If I want to select cols which name doesn't included `math`, how should I do that? for example, the rest of cols are not all start with ELA?

Comment: @Stataq you can add `everything()` at the end in `select` statement in the second block of code at the end

Comment: For `mutate(Total.E =  rowSums(select(., starts_with('ELA')),`, can I write as sth like `mutate(Total.E =  rowSums(select(., !starts_with('Math'))`?

Comment: @Stataq you can use `-` i..e `df %>% mutate(Total = rowSums(., na.rm = TRUE), .before = 'Math1') %>% mutate(Total.M = rowSums(dplyr::select(cur_data(), -Total, -starts_with('Math')), na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: Here, I am removing the 'Total' also in the selection because that column is also created first, and we don't want to use that in `rowSums`